# How can I find the relative extrema of the function?

Tags: calculus

I already found the partial derivatives of the function. They are the following:
fx= 2y-2x^3
fy= 2x-2y^3
fxx=-6x^2
fyy=-6y^2
fxy=2
And then I set the fx and fy equal to 0. I got y=x^3 and x=y^3. I just got stuck afterwards because there are no points given to me for x and y.
[image]

Comment: The maximum is given by $6$ and the minimum doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You did ok with the derivatives. Now $x=y^3,\;y=x^3$ shall hold simultaneously.
Put them as $x=y^3=x^9$, so which are the values of $x$ such that $x=x^9$, clearly $x=0$ and $x=1$ and $x=-1$ (in the finite).
Can you continue now ?